# Altering Data format of Array and Removing Key/Value Pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am pulling some email addresses data from our db to print to a file in our Node project. That code looks like this:

```
  const sql = `${query}`;
  let emailRecords = await this.mariaDB.query(sql);
  let data = JSON.stringify(emailRecords);
  fs.writeFileSync(appRoot + "/public/email-lists/staff-emails.json", data);
```

That gives me data that looks like this:

```
[ { email: 'email1@yahoo.com' },
  { email: 'email2@hotmail.com' },
  { email: 'samp2@yahoo.com' },
  { email: 'samp3@gmail.com' } ]
```

What I want to do is get rid of the key/value pairs, and end up with an array of just email addresses, like so:

```
[ 'email1@yahoo.com',
  'email2@hotmail.com',
  'samp2@yahoo.com',
  'samp3@gmail.com' ]
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to accomplish this, as 'filter()' is used to return a subset of the original array based on matching criteria. Here I want all of the original data, but trimmed like I describe above. Should I use regex here? Something else?

Comment: You can use map to create a new array

Comment: With destructuring: `const emails = data.map(({ email }) => email)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map high order function to create a new array like this:

```
const emails = data.map(e => { return e.email })
```

the new variable emails is a new array with the values that you need.